What type of roof has differing pitches and an offset ridge?
This was the house I grew up in. Besides the houses in this neighbourhood, I have not seen this type anywhere else, in my limited experience.
The house is ~30x40 foot bungalow.  The roof peak ran front to back about 1/4 to 1/3 of the length. It was about 4 or 5ft high making a decent grade/slope on the narrow end and a very low slope on the wide end.
I think it was a tar and gravel cover, since I remember my dad tossing some gravel down(at me).


Open gable roof with an offset ridge. I think this is sometimes referred to as a saltbox roof (gable with unequal length runs), but most look quite a bit different from your image.

I'm not even sure it has two pitches. Just looks like an offset ridge.

@isherwood I think you are right. Must have been the perspective on the photo.

@isherwood  It did have two different pitches.  The difference did not show up in the picture, but the short side was steeper.

A saltbox is a roof to which an addition was made, making it look like, well, a salt box.

@Cheery   This is the original size/design of the house.

@crip659 My comment was meant to say that this is not really a saltbox, since it looks like originally designed like this

Besides the small neighbourhood I grew up in(and did not pay that much attention to house designs), I have not seen this type of roof.  Early 1960s if that helps.  Do not even think other neighbourhoods in the city(Laval) had this type(that I saw).

Will accept your answer in a day for name/s.

a regular saltbox  has an extra floor under the high end of the roof. and the high end is usually the front.
